# CSS - 2 background images for a list item

Tags: html, css

I am using an image for the bottom border of a list items. I want to use a bullet image on the left for each of the item as well. So how can I use 2 background images for a list item? Currently I have following:

```
li{
    width:200px;
    padding:3px 5px;
    background: url(images/dot.png) repeat-x left bottom;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

---

**Using a bullet image:**

---

```
li 
{
   list-style-image: url('bullet.png');
}
```

Just add it to your existing style:

```
li
{
    width:200px;
    padding:3px 5px;
    background: url(bg.png) repeat-x left bottom;
    list-style-image: url('bullet.png');
}
```

---

**ADDON (CSS3 Variant)**

---

If you need some special effects you should use CSS3's multi-layered Backgrounds. (With effects I mean size, position or repeat)

```
li{
    width:200px;
    padding:3px 5px;
    background: url(images/dot.png) no-repeat left bottom,
         url(images/image.png) repeat-x right top;
}
```

Comment: Now that you extended your answer, it's nearly perfect. If you explain why not to use CSS3 (compatibility), this should be checked as ANSWER

Comment: Since CSS1, supported in all the modern browsers.

Answer (score 2):

First image is Top Layer (only in CSS3

```
    li{
        width:200px;
        padding:3px 5px;
        background: url(images/dot.png) no-repeat left bottom,
url(images/image.png) repeat-x right top;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be a CSS3 feature. http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/

Comment: :/ Well, I guess you didn't. Good answer though.

Answer (score 1):

The CSS3 is supporting this feature and all latest browsers will support it.

please have a look at here: http://www.zenelements.com/blog/css3-background-images/

Comment: This is not an answer on how to do this. either post a link or a code snippet. Answers like this will not help anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I recommend jim's solution, but here's an alternative solution, if you don't want to use `list-style-image` (say, if you are using a spritemap).

In case you need to optimize for non-CSS3 compliant browsers, you could put a `<span/>` or `<div/>` inside the `<li/>`, with a background image on each.

Comment: markup wise it's very bad practice.. Possible, but too much of a workaround to be helpful.

Comment: Oh, I don't deny it's technically not correct (which is why I stated that Jim's answer should be the accepted one), but it is a working solution nonetheless, and someone might find it useful.